# Rectangle of Death -- Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

*(NOTE: Updates 1-5 below)*

I have a Twitter-Bootstrap based responsive web page, and the top-left corner of the page has a rectangular-shaped zone which is completely dead, but only on Mobile Safari (I haven't tested on Android).

***Dead, defined:***

- Various buttons in the dead zone cannot be clicked
- Swiping up/down in the dead zone does **not** scroll the page up/down.

***I added the following code:***

```
$('*').click(function(){ 
  console.log($(this)); 
});
```

... and when I activated the mobile safari JS console, I noticed that the dead zone ***had become shifted up equal to the pixel height of the console strip!***. Ie., the dead zone had shrunk. Furthermore, the console logged all clicks ***except*** for those performed in the dead zone.

---

***UPDATE #1:***

Per advice from the comments I...

1) Double-checked *fixed*-positioned elements:

```
        $('*').click(function() { 
            console.log('checking for fixed elements...');
            $('*').each(function() {
                if ($(this).css('position') == 'fixed') {
                    console.log($(this));
                }
            })
        });
```

... it turned out my Bootstrap ***modal*** dialogs were all fixed position in mobile. I removed *all* of the dialogs and the problem persisted.

2) Added the following CSS code....

```
* { outline: 1px solid red; }
```

Here is the iPhone screenshot. (The blue box I added afterwards in photoshop to approximate the dead zone)...

[image: dead-zone screenshot]

---

***UPDATE #2:*** OK, this is ridiculous. I started stripping stuff out of my code.This what I ended up with, and the problem persists!...

```
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

---

***UPDATE #3***: This is likely a safari bug and has nothing to do with my webpage. (see update #2 below). I force-closed safari and when reopened the problem disappeared.

---

***UPDATE #4***: The problem reappeared :( Maybe it is my web page after all and not a safari fluke. However, it seems to happen randomly... Force-closing the browser will fix it for a while until it comes back again.

---

***UPDATE #5***: Once the dead zone appears, after navigating to another web page the dead zone is still there.

---

Comment: See if you can determine what element is in the dead space (probably can do it using a PC browser, unless the layout you have defined is different for mobile). Mobile Safari still has trouble with `position:fixed` and `z-index`, so it may be a hidden element sitting atop your elements.

Comment: Unfortunately the element doesn't show up in my desktop browsers. I don't think that anything has position:fixed because the responsive layout turns off fixed positioning for anything less than 768px or there about.

Comment: Debugging with CSS, using something like `* { opacity: 0.5; outline: 1px solid red; }`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. still no luck (see edit above)

Comment: What if you rotate? And I'd blame the Bootstrap menu in the top left corner; you know you also get that when making a regular browser smaller? And are things different for Retina/non-Retina? (Testable in a iPhone simulator.)

Comment: @Arjan, when I go horizontal the problem goes away. Look at update #2 above. I'm not kidding.

Comment: So using the original full-blown site also does not make the problem re-appear (since restarting Safari)?

Comment: @Arjan, good question. It seems to be working. However, I've been working on this problem for a few days and am pretty sure that I have restarted the browser during that time... but my memory is not so good.

Comment: ... seems the problem is back. see update #4

Comment: You might consider giving a link to the page somewhere in the question, even if most people are unable to run it in the browser you have issues with, it might help them spot the problem.

Comment: By and wide I've found that fixed positioning on iOS is an extremely mixed bag, and un-interactable / unrendered zones is something that can come up as a result. My site didn't make use of any frameworks, and my solution, according to various dubious test cases I set up, involved the following:

 * Making sure the fixed position content sat outside of scrolling/zooming content, DOM nesting-wise.
 * transform/translating scrolling content rather than repositioning where possible.

Any chance you can upload a version of your site with all sensitive content stripped out so we can try to debug?

Comment: Here's a sample url. I don't know a sure-fire way to induce the dead-zone but it appeared for me after clicking the "Invite Friends" link at the bottom which shows a modal dialog that has fixed-positioning.... 
https://theviplist.at/thehookah

Comment: I would have started by validating the HTML, then start debugging if the problem persisted! [Try it out](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftheviplist.at%2Fthehookah&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3), take a look at what it says about "Line 1376".

Answer (score 3):

There are only about a million possibilities to this issue. I would start by plugging your device into your computer and opening Safari. make sure Develop mode is turned on in your preferences. From the develop menu select your device, and inspect the elements. It's amazing what you'll be able to find. Start by adding "display:none" to each element until you find what your problem is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you completely removed all the modals? i had a issue like this before the problem was that my modals where laking the class hide, without this the modal is just faded to opacity 0

example:
class="modal hide fade"

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following CSS property for the problematic element:

```
<selector> {
   pointer-events: all; 
}
```

where `<selector>` stands for the element selector in question